# having some EPERM not permitted

Tags: node.js, next.js

here is my code

```
npx create-next-app jprl
```

wondering what the solution? here the error when i put `npx create-next-app jprl`

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\John'
command not found: create-next-app
```